# wpf controls style Foreground inheritance from window

Tags: wpf, properties, controls

Why when i set property FontSize in window :

```
<Window x:Class= .....
    FontSize="16" >
```

it changing for all controls in window (for example in TextBox or Button)
but, when i change Foreground="Green" is change nothing?
Where can I find out more about such dependencies and get a list of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by the [`FrameworkPropertyMetadata.Inherits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.inherits?view=net-5.0) flag, which is set on the `FontSize` dependency property.

Be aware that the flag is also set on the `Foreground` property, so the value of a Window's Foreground will be inherited by e.g. all TextBlocks child elements.

---

There is usually a **Dependency Property Information** section in the **Remarks** in the property documentation, that shows which FrameworkPropertyMetadata flags are set on a dependency property.

Comment: how to change this flag for project?

Comment: You can't. You can only set it once when a property is declared.